# Программная подстановка нужного падежа для слов

Tags: java

Вот в том же ВК имена пользователей склоняется. Мне интересно, есть ли какой-то готовый способ, для того, чтобы изменять слово в зависимости нужного и указанного падежа?

Пример:
Есть некие локации. Допустим, вот одна из них - `Свалка`.

Есть предложения:
"В окружности `%locaion%` замечен противник."
"Было найдено на `%locaion%` тогда-то тогда."

И тому подобное. Мы понимаем, что если просто вместо плейсхолдера `%location%` подставить `Свалка`, то получится дичь. Есть ли решение подобной задачи или придётся расписывать каждый падеж для каждой(в данном случае) локации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я поддерживаю coder675. Если локаций не миллион, то самый простой вариант: потратить полчаса на то, чтобы просклонять их в нужные падежи, а потом сделать свой "умный" `.replace`, который умел бы работать так:

```
all_words = {..., "Свалка": ["Свалки", "Свалке" ...] ...}

// P - предложный
// G - родительный

"Я никогда не был на {P}".replace("Свалка") // => "... Свалке"
"Что ты знаешь о {P}".replace("Свалка") // => "... Свалке"
"Это со {G}".replace("Свалка") // => "... Свалки"
"В окружности {G} замечен противник".replace("Свалка") // => "... Свалки"
```

Answer (score 3):

[Библиотека Padeg](https://bintray.com/jbaruch/jbaruch-maven/russian-case-inflection/3.3.0.24)
[Вот тут пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/161335/)

Comment: Пожалуйста, публикуйте ссылки в качестве дополнения к вашему ответу, а не вместо него. После изменения или удаления материалов по ссылке ваш ответ в нынешней редакции не будет иметь смысла

Answer (score 1):

То что просто для человека, для программы совсем не просто. Проще указывать падеж. чем научить программу русскому языку. Хотя сейчас есть нейросети, но это очень сложно по моему.

Comment: Да, спустя час поисков я понял, что легче просклонять самому)